# $.ajax + authentication + `@` in username

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, http, email, basic-authentication

I am creating a web app which uses jQuery to authenticate:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/session/create?format=json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    username: $("#signin-email").val(),
    password: $("#signin-password").val(),
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.success) {
        success = true;
      }
    }
  });
```

The problem is that the code **only** makes the AJAX-request when the `username` does not include things like an `@` (probably because the @ is a seperator for authentication and host in the URL), which is required in my app. Can anyone help me with how I can do this? I do not mind changing the back-end a little bit, but requiring users to have an `@`-less email is not an option.

Oh, my back-end is a Ruby-on-Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace all @s with %40. The @ is namely teh seperator between the authentication and host in the URL (e.g. http://someone:password@example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't replicate described behavior: request is being sent for @-logins. Are you sure that this is not a server problem (e.g. response isn't in json format)?
(Btw, I'm using standard jquery, suppose there are no hacks for one that RoR shipped with)

Comment: Does Rails ship with jQuery? I didn't know. I usually empty the 'public' folder after I created a new project...
No it's not a server problem since when I sign in by entering the URL and fill in the email and password in Safari's dialog, it does work.

Comment: The problem seems strange to me to – jQuery seems to pass the username and password params directly to the browser's XMLHttpRequest class, and I would assume any escaping is done automatically...